# upgrading mongodb to 4.4 from 4.2 failed with "...unsupported WiredTiger file version..."

Tags: mongodb

I have upgraded my mongodb to 4.4 from 4.2.
I thought that my setFeatureCompatibilityVersion was 4.2 but i was wrong. it was 3.x
so i ran the 4.2 instance again to set setFeatureCompatibilityVersion to 4.2 but this fail

and now i get this error

```
db version v4.2.3
....so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'
2020-08-26T21:38:45.656+0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1598467125:655293][2016:140717972479568], connection: __log_open_verify, 926: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 3, and the file is version 4: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw: [1598467125:655293][2016:140717972479568], connection: __log_open_verify, 926: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build only supports versions up to 3, and the file is version 4: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-08-26T21:38:45.694+0300 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
```

please any help will be appreciated i am in dead end
my last backup is a day ago and i don't wanna a miss my data

again Thanks in advance to any one.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a backup NOW.

Second, read the upgrading guides for each version from whatever your FCV is right now through 4.2, and follow the instructions.

Third, you need to increase your FCV one release at a time, e.g. 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 etc.

Comment: 10x first for the quick response. but it ran on my 4.2 before. is there any way to run my good old 4.2 and set the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion before

Comment: all previus instances i am trying to run are failing 3.6, 4.0, 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok. to whom it might help

```
my 4.2.x version was 4.2.3

what i did is download the latest 4.2.x version that is 4.2.9
i run my data folder against 4.2.9 binaries and voilla works.
now i can take a backup
next will change the FCV to 4.2.
next use the 4.4 binaries against my data folder
next change the FCV to 4.4
```

:)
10x2all